# Where or what is "Saphoy"?

Tags: germany, baptism-records, 17th-century, wurttemberg

The uploaded image is a baptismal record from 18 Sep 1646 in Winnenden near Stuttgart, Wuerttemberg. I found the record at
"Württemberg, Germany, Lutheran Baptisms, Marriages, and Burials, 1500-1985, Winnenden u Winnental, Taufen u Heiraten 1558-1760, [https://www.ancestrylibrary.ca/imageviewer/collections/61023/images/1056954-00418"](https://www.ancestrylibrary.ca/imageviewer/collections/61023/images/1056954-00418%22).

I can read everything well enough, but I have trouble with the interpretation of Jeremias Poppel's place of origin. He is described as a shopkeeper from "Saphoy". Where or what is that? (I couldn't find anything useful in Meyer's Gazetteer.) Did the recorder mean "Savoy"?

[image: Baptismal record for Michael Poppel, Winnenden 1646]

Comment: Can you add the date of the baptism, religion etc to give some context?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Jeremias Boppel did indeed come from Savoy.

Apparently Savoy was experiencing overpopulation and food shortages in the early seventeenth century. Some plying their trade as traveling vendors came to southern Germany, some settling in Baden (particularly Wolfach), others in Wurttemberg. Jeremias Boppel (original name "Popelet") registered a birth in Backnang in 1636, but seems to have been moving around for another eight or ten years until he settled in Hoefen near Winnenden.